# EF 6 Skip all records where column is null, from results get row 'N'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following EF Linq query:

```
var face = de.Faces.OrderBy(f => f.id).Skip(recordNumber)
              .FirstOrDefault(fd => fd.FuzzyHash != null);
```

What it is supposed to be doing, but failing is:

1. Get Nth `recordNumber` from Faces which has an existing `FuzzyHash`

**Could someone fix the query and explain the fix to me - what am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Not a Linq-to-Entities expert, so I may be wrong, but it looks to me like you need to filter the rows with null values *before* you use `Skip()`. So what you're looking for is probably `de.Faces.Where(f => f.FuzzyHash != null).OrderBy(f => f.id).Skip(recordNumber)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current query would skip N records, and then take the first record that has a `FuzzyHash`.

What you want to do is first filter the records to include only the ones that have a `FuzzyHash` and then skip N records like this:

```
var face = de.Faces
    .Where(fd => fd.FuzzyHash != null)
    .OrderBy(f => f.id)
    .Skip(recordNumber) //shouldn't this be recordNumber - 1?
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Agreed `recordNumber - 1` if 1-based.  +1 for nice formatting (for otherwise identical answers) :)

Comment: recordNumber is 0 based in which I do not use the skip variant of the query.

Comment: Right, if `recordNumber` is zero-based, then you should skip `recordNumber` items.

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove all records where `FuzzyHash` is null.

```
var face = de.Faces.Where(r => null != r.FuzzyHash).OrderBy(f => f.id).Skip(recordNumber)
          .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think this should work, though the filter in `FirstOrDefault` is superfluous.

Answer (score 3):

EF Linq operates much like you would think out this problem logically.

> I need to get the nth record from an ordered list of Faces where some column is not null.

First, get your list of not null column Faces, then order, then skip, then get the record.

```
var face = de.Faces.Where(fd => fd.FuzzyHash != null).OrderBy(f =>
f.id).Skip(recordNumber).FirstOrDefault();
```